# how to change app name and package name of an apk?

Tags: android, apk

I decompiled an apk and I made a couple of modifications. When I tried to recompile it I got that error :

```
Compiling APK file...

/c "java -Xmx1024m -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\APK Easy Tool\Apktool\apktool_2.4.1.jar" b -f -o "C:\Users\asus\Documents\APK Easy Tool\2-Recompiled APKs\b83ba6fc.apk" "C:\Users\asus\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\{b83ba6fc-4bdd-4c0b-badb-d3d46d6248ea}" "

I: Using Apktool 2.4.1
I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
I: Smaling smali_assets folder into assets.dex...
..\..\..\Users\asus\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\{b83ba6fc-4bdd-4c0b-badb-d3d46d6248ea}\smali_assets\com\facebook\ads\internal\androidx\support\v4\view\AbsSavedState$1.smali[13,11] Class Lcom/facebook/ads/internal/androidx/support/v4/view/AbsSavedState$1; has already been interned
Could not smali file: com/facebook/ads/internal/androidx/support/v4/view/AbsSavedState$1.smali



------------------------------------------
```

This is the apk easy tool log output.

after making those changes :

- I changed the app name
- I changed the package name

Comment: Have you modified one of the classes that are mentioned in the error message ? BTW: Apktool 2.4.1 is outdated there is already v 2.5.0 available.

Comment: How/where did you modify the app/package name? You should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the application and package name using tools such as APK Editor see more [here](https://apkpure.com/br/apk-editor-pro/com.heagoo.apkeditor), in a simple edition of AndroidManifest.xml and strings.xml, the change process is very simple, it is not recommended that the package name also be changed compatibility issues), but APK Editor modifies for you, the second reason why when you tried to compress again and got the error could be due to a wrong modification, please check again, and I strongly recommend that you consider using the tool mentioned by me, however if you are modifying it correctly you can get the new version of APK Tool [Here](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), also make sure that the apk does not use any kind of obfuscation.